# how do I call my functions in .net

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2010, c#-4.0

I am learning .net and writing a service by following the tutorial below http://www.beansoftware.com/NET-Tutorials/Create-Windows-Services.aspx

The windows service gets installed successfully and it starts too. But when I change the file name or delete a file or add a file, it doesnt add any information to my log file which is in
C:\Folder\FolderLog.txt

I see 3 methods for FolderWatcher_**** but I dont see a call to those in the code. I am very new to .net so I am not sure how they are being called

here is my complete code

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Linq;
using System.ServiceProcess;
using System.Text;
using System.IO;

    namespace Watcher
    {
        public partial class Watcher : ServiceBase
        {
            public Watcher()
            {
                InitializeComponent();
            }

            protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
            {

            }

            protected override void OnStop()
            {
            }

            private void FolderWatcher_Created(object sender, System.IO.FileSystemEventArgs e)
            {
                TextWriter writer = new StreamWriter("C:\\folder\\FolderLog.txt", true);
                writer.WriteLine(DateTime.Now + " A new folder/file with name " + e.Name + " has been created. ");
                writer.Close();
            }

            private void FolderWatcher_Deleted(object sender, System.IO.FileSystemEventArgs e)
            {
                TextWriter writer = new StreamWriter("C:\\folder\\FolderLog.txt", true);
                writer.WriteLine(DateTime.Now + " A new folder/file with name " + e.Name + " has been deleted. ");
                writer.Close();
            }

            private void FolderWatcher_Renamed(object sender, System.IO.RenamedEventArgs e)
            {
                TextWriter writer = new StreamWriter("C:\\folder\\log.txt", true);
                writer.WriteLine(DateTime.Now + " A new folder/file with name " + e.Name + " has been renamed. ");
                writer.Close();
            }


        }
    }
```

I have followed every single step in that tutorial. I have not seen anything that descibes how these methods are called. Any help would be great

Comment: Maybe, and I'm not sure of it because I never created a service, there could be permission issues. Windows 7 expecially is a bit strict (is better) about permission, you can't write on some paths if you aren't administrator. Hope this help in some way

Comment: Did you follow step 6 in the tutorial - hook the designer-created FolderWatcher to the event handlers shown above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you register the events of the watcher instance "`FolderWatcher`" to the events handlers in your code, you can do that at service designer or in the constructor of the service, like:

```
public Watcher()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    FolderWatcher.Created += FolderWatcher_Created;//when created FolderWatcher_Created will be called
    FolderWatcher.Deleted += FolderWatcher_Deleted;//when deleted call FolderWatcher_Deleted will be called
    FolderWatcher.Renamed += FolderWatcher_Renamed;//when renamed FolderWatcher_Renamed will be called
}
```

Comment: I have a similar question here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7101326/running-a-batch-file-from-c may be you can help there too. thanks

Answer (score 3):

The tutorial probably has you adding a `FileSystemWatcher` in the design mode surface for your service.  In design mode, select that object and in its event handlers, select the appropriate methods of your class.