# Execute a Batch File From C#

Tags: c#, command-prompt, batch-file

I have a small problem. Okay let's say from my C# console application I want to run a batch file that will take an argument. The string variable at the stop of my C# application will be the string argument to pass to the batch file. How would I go about doing it?

Here is my code so far my C# console program:

```
//String argument to pass to the batch file
string message = "Hello World";

System.Diagnostics.Process process = new System.Diagnostics.Process();

//startInfo.WindowStyle = System.Diagnostics.ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
startInfo.FileName = "Greetings.bat";
startInfo.Arguments = "/C " + message;
process.StartInfo = startInfo;
process.Start();
```

My Batch File

```
CLS
@ECHO OFF
ECHO %1
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [C# Service cannot execute batch file?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/361097/c-sharp-service-cannot-execute-batch-file)

Comment: Or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7101326/running-a-batch-file-from-c-sharp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can give argument like this.

```
ProcessStartInfo psi = new ProcessStartInfo(filePath);
psi.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden; 
psi.Arguments = "value1";
```

Comment: Note that with this code you are supplying one argument 'value1value2'