# Starting a batch file in C# and then waiting for it to exit before continuing

Tags: c#, .net, batch-file

The problem is that the WaitForExit does not wait until the batch file quits.  It comes back almost right away.

I'm starting my batch file as follows:

```
            ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo(batchFile);
            startInfo.UseShellExecute = true;
            startInfo.Arguments = arguments;

            using (Process p = Process.Start(startInfo))
            {
                p.WaitForExit();
            }
```

I tried with and without `UseShellExecute`.

Comment: [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7101534/16623) may help.

Comment: if WaitForExit() dosen't work try to follow [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.exited.aspx)

Comment: That didn't work either. It must be something unique about this batch file.  The batch file calls other processes, but does wait until they all quit before it returns.

Answer (score 1):

You could try running cmd with a "/c yourbatchfile" as command line arguments instead.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you can do it redirecting the `StdOut` and read it until it closes.

Took this idea from [this similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/361097/c-sharp-service-cannot-execute-batch-file).

Adapting your snippet, that would be:

```
ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo(batchFile);
//startInfo.UseShellExecute = true;
startInfo.Arguments = arguments;
startInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;

Process p = Process.Start(startInfo);
String output = proc.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
```